# Remote debugging azure

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-2.0

Is there a way to step through server code remotely on azure with vs code? We've been running this a lot lately, but basically these bugs only show up on azure but not on local host. Do you guys have tips on debugging these types of bugs? I've been putting in logs and changes on areas i think might be a culprit. But deploying to azure usually takes 20-30 minutes so it's not very practical to debug this way,

EDIT:
Sorry I forgot to mention It's hosting my web server/ client app

Comment: debug what, exactly. A function/web app/container or any of the 1001 services offered?

Comment: If you are using Azure App service, you could [remote debugging Azure WebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug) with VS.  We also could [remote debug cloudservice with VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-debug-cloud-services-virtual-machines).